# Avoid duplicates for joining two tables with one of them having GROUP BY on SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

Avoid duplicates for joining two tables with one of them having GROUP BY on SQL server

On SQL server, I have a table

```
Id1, id2, id3, val1, val2
1      15  20    110    25.69 
1      15  20    120    26.17 
2      19  58    110    17.11 
3      66  75    129    9.55    
3      66  75    268    66.82
```

I need to find all rows that  val1 has more than one distinct values.

The expected output should be :

```
Id1, id2, id3, val1, val2
 1      15  20    110    25.69 
 1      15  20    120    26.17 
 3      66  75    129    9.55    
 3      66  75    268    66.82
```

Because for same

```
  Id1, id2, id3
```

they have more than one value in "val1".

I know how to do it in this:

```
SELECT Id1, id2, id3, val1, val2
FROM  table1 AS a
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT Id1, id2, id3
  FROM table 1
  GROUP BY Id1, id2, id3
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT val1) > 1 
 ) AS b
ON a.id1 = b.id1 and a.id2 = b.id2 and a.id3 = b.id3
```

But, this may have duplicated rows because

```
  Id1, id2, id3
  1      15  20
```

Can be joined to get

```
Id1, id2, id3, val1, val2
1      15  20    110    25.69 
1      15  20    120    26.17 
1      15  20    110    25.69 
1      15  20    120    26.17
```

I do not want to use "distinct" for floating point numbers.

How to improve the query ? 
Is it possible to do it without sub-query ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use window functions:

```
select Id1, id2, id3, val1, val2
from (select t1.*,
             min(val1) over (partition by id1, id2, id3) as min1,
             max(val1) over (partition by id1, id2, id3) as max1
      from t1
     ) t1
where min1 <> max1;
```

Comment: @user3448011 . . . If there are more than 2 `val1` distinct values, then the minimum and maximum are still different, so the logic works.

Comment: it should be  min(val1) over (partition by id1, id2, id3) ?

Comment: @user3448011 . . . Your question does explicitly mention the three columns, so they should be in the `partition by`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WHERE EXISTS`:

```
DECLARE @tablename TABLE (Id1 int, id2 int, id3 int, val1 int, val2 decimal(16,2))
INSERT INTO @tablename VALUES
 (1, 15, 20, 110, 25.69)
,(1, 15, 20, 120, 26.17)
,(2, 19, 58, 110, 17.11)
,(3, 66, 75, 129, 9.55)  
,(3, 66, 75, 268, 66.82) 

SELECT *
  FROM @tablename T1
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
                 FROM @tablename T2 
                WHERE T2.Id1 = T1.Id1
                  AND T2.id2 = T1.id2
                  AND T2.id3 = T1.id3
                  AND T2.val1 <> T1.val1)
```

Produces output:

```
Id1 id2 id3 val1 val2
1   15  20  110  25.69
1   15  20  120  26.17
3   66  75  129  9.55
3   66  75  268  66.82
```

Answer (score 0):

This will find all repetitions of Val1 and remove all but the first of them from the result:

```
select *
from (
    select *
         , row_number() over(partition by val1 
                             order by (select null)) rn
    from yourtable
    ) d
where rn = 1
```